# Trying to fetch data from supabase and building a gallery of images but get "Result is not iterable" in Next JS 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, supabase

I'm using Next JS 13 and got a table on supabase which I want to get my pictures to build a gallery.

My code is the following:

`app/products/page.tsx`

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';
import Gallery from '@/components/Gallery';

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const supabaseAdmin = createClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL || '',
    process.env.SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY || ''
  );

  const { data } = await supabaseAdmin.from('images').select('*').order('id');
  return {
    props: {
      images: data,
    },
  };
}

export default function ProductsPage({ images }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Gallery images={images} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Got a components folder as well with

```
import BlurImage from './BlurImage';

export default function Gallery({ images }: { images: Image[] }) {
  return (
    <div className="mx-auto max-w-2xl py-16 px-4 sm:py-24 sm:px-6 lg:max-w-7xl lg:px-8">
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-y-10 gap-x-6 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 xl:gap-x-8">
        {images.map((image) => (
          <BlurImage key={image.id} image={image} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
'use client';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { useState } from 'react';

function cn(...classes: string[]) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ');
}

function BlurImage({ image }: { image: Image }) {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="group">
      <div className="aspect-w-1 aspect-h-1 w-full overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-gray-200 xl:aspect-w-7 xl:aspect-h-8">
        <Image
          alt=""
          src={image.imageSrc}
          layout="fill"
          objectFit="cover"
          className={cn(
            'duration-700 ease-in-out group-hover:opacity-75',
            isLoading
              ? 'scale-110 blur-2xl grayscale'
              : 'scale-100 blur-0 grayscale-0'
          )}
          onLoadingComplete={() => setLoading(false)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BlurImage;
```

I was previously using getStaticProps on page.tsx but I saw that you can't use that on the app directory anymore, not too sure what to do about it.

This is my table on supabase:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pWnM.png)

This is the error I'm getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL4uF.png)

Comment: can you `console.log(data)` after this line `const { data } = await supabaseAdmin.from('images').select('*').order('id')`

Comment: Sure! I get the same error and an array of objects with with my 49 pictures:

Answer (score 1):

you should read about [generate-static-params](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params).

> The generateStaticParams function can be used in combination with
> dynamic route segments to statically generate routes at build time
> instead of on-demand at request time.

this function runs on build time to build the static paths. this is similar to `getStaticPaths`. It does not return `props` object which is passed to the component as prop. It returns an array of all the slugs (or all the unique properties that you defined) that stored in the database. you will see the examples in the documentation link. you dont need `getStaticParams` in your code. you can define your code as `async` and fetch the data directly inside the component:

```
// I marked the component as async
export default async function ProductsPage() {
  const supabaseAdmin = createClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL || '',
    process.env.SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY || ''
  );

  const { data } = await supabaseAdmin.from('images').select('*').order('id');
  return (
    <div>
      {/* data is passed as the prop data */}
      <Gallery images={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```